# One line of if..else if.. else statement

Tags: javascript

I tried to write one line `if..elseif..else` statement but it always goes in `else if`.

```js
var x = "192.168.1.1";
x = x == ("google.com") ? ("true google.com") : (("yahoo.com") ? ("true yahoo.com") : ("192.168.1.1"));
console.log(x);
```

Is there something I am missing? Why does it always go in `else if`?

Comment: Don't. Just don't. Brevity is not a virtue when it makes your code hard to read and debug.

Comment: While you can nest ternary conditions why on earth would you want to? It is horrible to read/debug and you probably don't get that much performance increase. Why not just straight if/else blocks?

Comment: @Quentin isn't it faster than lines of `if else if else`?

Comment: Man made Javascript obfuscation..

Comment: @Eniss — I doubt it. I doubt even more that any performance differences will be perceptable. http://wiki.c2.com/?PrematureOptimization

Comment: just avoid using such kind of confusing conditions.
 May be some day someone will ask a question "i can't understand the code, please! help me " :p

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You missed the `x == (""yahoo.com"")` statement

```js
var x = "192.168.1.1";
x = (x == "google.com") ?
        "true google.com" :
        (x == "yahoo.com") ?
            "true yahoo.com" :
        "192.168.1.1";
// --------------------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^------------------------------------
console.log(x);
```

But it will be more readable with `if - else if - else` statements. Don't make your code concise if it will decrease the readability.

Answer (score 0):

This does not answer the question

> Why does it always go in `else if`?

but it could help with

> Is there something I am missing?

Yes, you mis some clarity for further use and a clear pattern, how to get for a given string another string.

You could use an object, which is easy to maintain for the keyed values.

> ```
> values = {
>     "google.com": "true google.com",
>     "yahoo.com": "true yahoo.com",
>     default : "192.168.1.1"
> };
> ```

The call works with a default operator `||` (logical OR):

```
x = values[x] || values.default;
```

```js
var x = "192.168.1.1",
    values = {
        "google.com": "true google.com",
        "yahoo.com": "true yahoo.com",
        default : "192.168.1.1"
    };

x = values[x] || values.default;
console.log(x);
```

Comment: nice dv. maybe you add why.

Comment: Not me who down-voted, but it's most likely because it never answered the OP's question, but gave an alternative method.  I'm personally not against that, but I do know some on SO can get a bit Anal about these things.

Answer (score 0):

Your ternary operation

```
x = x == ("google.com") ? ("true google.com") : (("yahoo.com") ? ("true yahoo.com") : ("192.168.1.1"));
```

can be thought of as `if-else if-else` block as follows:

```
if(x == ("google.com")) {
   x = "true google.com";
}
else {
   if("yahoo.com") {
       x = "true yahoo.com"; //Always true since it is a non-empty string
   }
   else {
       x = "192.168.1.1"
   }
}
```

So since you are initializing x to "192.168.1.1", it obviously is not equal to the the string specified ("google.com") in the first condition (`if` block). So it moves on to the else block and evaluates the `if` condition inside the `else` block. This `if` block in turn only checks if a string literal "yahoo.com" is empty or not. Since it is not empty, the condition is satisfied.

For your purpose, you need to change that from `if("yahoo.com")` to `x == if("yahoo.com")`. However, once you make this change, it will always go to the else block because the first two conditions will never satisfy.